# BFS Implementation not working properly

Tags: c++, algorithm, shortest-path

Here is my BFS implementation which is returning me always 0. I should basically find the shortest path through this map, 1 - means it's a wall, 0 - means no wall. Where i'm mistaking?

```
class node { public: int x,y; };

int bfs(int x, int y)
{
    node start;
    int result = 0;
    start.x = 0;
    start.y = 0;
    std::queue<node> search_queue;
    bool visited[4][4];
    int map[4][4] = {
                    {0,1,0,1},
                    {0,0,0,0},
                    {1,0,1,0},
                    {0,1,0,0}
                };
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4; i ++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 4; j++)
        {
            visited[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
    search_queue.push(start);
    while(!search_queue.empty())
    {
        node top = search_queue.front();
        search_queue.pop();

        if (visited[top.x][top.y]) continue;
        if (map[top.x][top.y] == 1) continue;
            if (top.x < 0 || top.x >= 4) continue;
            if (top.y < 0 || top.y >= 4) continue;
        visited[top.x][top.y] = true;
        result++;
        node temp;

        temp.x = top.x+1;
        temp.y=top.y;
        search_queue.push(temp);

        temp.x = top.x-1;
        temp.y=top.y;
        search_queue.push(temp);

        temp.x = top.x;
        temp.y=top.y+1;
        search_queue.push(temp);

        temp.x = top.x;
        temp.y=top.y-1;
        search_queue.push(temp);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and i call it from main like that : `cout<<bfs(0,0);`

Comment: Shortest path to where? Go through a maze?

Comment: yes, to the [4][4] point.

Comment: BFS is used at Graph not Matrix, but i guess you can implement on a Matrix as well.

Comment: @OrelEraki A matrix is basically a graph where `V={all cells}, E={(u,v) | u is adjacent to v}`

Comment: Remember: indexes in `int map[4][4]` range from 0 to 3; you aren't going to get to the [4][4] point and have defined behaviour.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler added two if statements.

Comment: Those are important...also, you ignore the two input parameters to the function.  Presumably, the `start.x = 0;` should `start.x = x;` and likewise for `y`? As amended, I got the answer 10.  I suspect the answer should be 7.  Are you sure you're resetting `result` appropriately?  Or are you stacking enough context (should length of path to given point be part of the contex)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes i was ignoring those 2 parameters because they don't change anything since i initialize the starting point x (start.x) to 0 and so to y, but ok, in terms of correctness i changed that but it's strange, i still get the answer 0. can you post your code on pastebin or elsewhere to have a look? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Instrumenting path

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

class node { public: int x, y; };

int bfs(int x, int y)
{
    node start;
    int result = 0;
    start.x = x;
    start.y = y;
    std::queue<node> search_queue;
    bool visited[4][4];
    int map[4][4] =
    {
        {0, 1, 0, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0}
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            visited[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
    search_queue.push(start);
    while (!search_queue.empty())
    {
        node top = search_queue.front();
        search_queue.pop();

        if (visited[top.x][top.y])
            continue;
        if (map[top.x][top.y] == 1)
            continue;
        if (top.x < 0 || top.x >= 4)
            continue;
        if (top.y < 0 || top.y >= 4)
            continue;

        visited[top.x][top.y] = true;
        std::cout << "visit: [" << top.x << "][" << top.y << "]\n";
        result++;
        node temp;

        temp.x = top.x + 1;
        temp.y = top.y;
        search_queue.push(temp);

        temp.x = top.x - 1;
        temp.y = top.y;
        search_queue.push(temp);

        temp.x = top.x;
        temp.y = top.y + 1;
        search_queue.push(temp);

        temp.x = top.x;
        temp.y = top.y - 1;
        search_queue.push(temp);
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << bfs(0, 0);
}
```

produces:

```
visit: [0][0]
visit: [1][0]
visit: [1][1]
visit: [2][1]
visit: [1][2]
visit: [0][2]
visit: [1][3]
visit: [2][3]
visit: [3][3]
visit: [3][2]
10
```

One interesting point is that it reaches `[3][3]` and continues; you don't seem to have the end well defined. That accounts for one of the extra count (compared with the 7 that should be expected).  The `[2][1]` and `[0][2]` dead-ends account for the other two.  Basically, you need to decrement `result` when you follow a dead-end and reach the end.

#### Designating end point

Bounds checking changed after seeing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21348678/15168) by [iavr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2644390/iavr).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

class node { public: int x, y; };

int bfs(int bx, int by, int ex, int ey)
{
    node start;
    int result = 0;
    start.x = bx;
    start.y = by;
    std::queue<node> search_queue;
    bool visited[4][4];
    int map[4][4] =
    {
        {0, 1, 0, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0}
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            visited[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
    search_queue.push(start);
    while (!search_queue.empty())
    {
        node top = search_queue.front();
        search_queue.pop();

        if (top.x < 0 || top.x >= 4)
            continue;
        if (top.y < 0 || top.y >= 4)
            continue;
        if (visited[top.x][top.y])
            continue;
        if (map[top.x][top.y] == 1)
            continue;

        visited[top.x][top.y] = true;
        std::cout << "visit: [" << top.x << "][" << top.y << "]\n";
        result++;

        if (top.x == ex && top.y == ey)
            break;

        node temp;

        temp.x = top.x + 1;
        temp.y = top.y;
        search_queue.push(temp);

        temp.x = top.x - 1;
        temp.y = top.y;
        search_queue.push(temp);

        temp.x = top.x;
        temp.y = top.y + 1;
        search_queue.push(temp);

        temp.x = top.x;
        temp.y = top.y - 1;
        search_queue.push(temp);
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << bfs(0, 0, 3, 3);
}
```

Output:

```
visit: [0][0]
visit: [1][0]
visit: [1][1]
visit: [2][1]
visit: [1][2]
visit: [0][2]
visit: [1][3]
visit: [2][3]
visit: [3][3]
9
```

#### Getting the correct answer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

class node { public: int x, y, l; };

int bfs(int bx, int by, int ex, int ey)
{
    node start;
    int result = 0;
    start.x = bx;
    start.y = by;
    start.l = 1;
    std::queue<node> search_queue;
    bool visited[4][4];
    int map[4][4] =
    {
        {0, 1, 0, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0}
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            visited[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
    search_queue.push(start);
    while (!search_queue.empty())
    {
        node top = search_queue.front();
        search_queue.pop();

        if (visited[top.x][top.y])
            continue;
        if (map[top.x][top.y] == 1)
            continue;
        if (top.x < 0 || top.x >= 4)
            continue;
        if (top.y < 0 || top.y >= 4)
            continue;

        visited[top.x][top.y] = true;
        std::cout << "visit: [" << top.x << "][" << top.y << "] = " << top.l << "\n";

        result = top.l;
        if (top.x == ex && top.y == ey)
            break;

        node temp;

        temp.l = top.l + 1;

        temp.x = top.x + 1;
        temp.y = top.y;
        search_queue.push(temp);

        temp.x = top.x - 1;
        temp.y = top.y;
        search_queue.push(temp);

        temp.x = top.x;
        temp.y = top.y + 1;
        search_queue.push(temp);

        temp.x = top.x;
        temp.y = top.y - 1;
        search_queue.push(temp);
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << bfs(0, 0, 3, 3) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
visit: [0][0] = 1
visit: [1][0] = 2
visit: [1][1] = 3
visit: [2][1] = 4
visit: [1][2] = 4
visit: [0][2] = 5
visit: [1][3] = 5
visit: [2][3] = 6
visit: [3][3] = 7
7
```

Comment: Jonathan Leffler thanks dude! now i understand where the problem was!

Comment: I suppose I am a slow typer... If you need an implementation idea without adding extra data to your `node` data structure, check out my answer below

Comment: This may be correct on this matrix but not correct in general. You have to visit points by increasing order of distance, which is basically [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), as I point out in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The code as given produces 10. With a few modifications, here is a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f86a8d22ca9537e6). One modification is that input `x`, `y` is set as the start point, I guess this was the intent as pointed out by Jonathan Leffler above. A second modification is that range checking now takes place **before** pushing into the queue, so the while loop is modified as follows:

```
    while(!search_queue.empty())
    {
        node top = search_queue.front();
        search_queue.pop();

        if (visited[top.x][top.y]) continue;
        if (map[top.x][top.y] == 1) continue;
        visited[top.x][top.y] = true;
        result++;
        node temp;

        temp.y = top.y;

        if (top.x < 3)
        {
            temp.x = top.x + 1;
            search_queue.push(temp);
        }

        if (top.x > 0)
        {
            temp.x = top.x - 1;
            search_queue.push(temp);
        }

        temp.x = top.x;

        if (top.y < 3)
        {
            temp.y = top.y + 1;
            search_queue.push(temp);
        }

        if (top.y > 0)
        {
            temp.y = top.y - 1;
            search_queue.push(temp);
        }
    }
```

Now, assuming that the start point is within range (and you may add another check for that), this loop will always move within range and it will never put out-of-range point into the queue, saving a number of computations.

Also, as your conditions are initially written, you access arrays `visited` and `map` **before** range checking, which may have bad results.

Most importanly, if your goal is to `find the shortest path through this map`, then this algorithm is not appropriate. Number `10` is the number of all positions that can be visited starting from (0, 0). It is not the shortest path to anywhere. What you need is a shortest path algorithm, and since graph weights are positive here, a simple option is [Dijsktra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

This requires only a few modifications to your code, but I leave this to you. Basically you will need to replace array `visited` by an integer array `distance` designating the minimum distance to every point from the start position, initialized to "infinity" and only decreasing. And your queue will have to be replaced by a priority queue, such that points are visited by increasing distance.

Comment: +1: Good point about bounds checking before accessing out of bounds!

Answer (score 1):

Your code just counts the number of accessible cells. I assume you want to count only the cells between start and end (the `result` variable is useless in this context). I usually use a data structure like this:

```
std::queue<pair<node,int> > search_queue;
```

When you extract an element from the queue, code looks like this:

```
    node top = search_queue.front().first;
    int current_length = search_queue.front().second;
    // if (top == end) return current_length;  (this is the value you are interested in)
```

Adding the next elements to the queue would of course, look like this:

```
    search_queue.add(make_pair(temp, current_length + 1));
```

I hope the full code is easy to get from here.

Answer (score 0):

another method

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
            self.items=[]
    def enqueue(self,item):
            self.items.append(item)
    def dequeue(self):
            return self.items.pop(0)
    def isEmpty(self):
            return self.items==[]
    def size(self):
            return len(self.items)

class Vertex:
    def __init__(self,id):
            self.id=id
            self.color="white"
            self.dist=None
            self.pred=None
            self.sTime=0
            self.fTime=0
            self.connectedTo={}

    def addNeighbor(self,nbr,weight):
            self.connectedTo[nbr]=weight
    def __str__(self):
            return str(self.id)+"connectedTo"+str([x for x in self.connectedTo])
    def getConnection(self):
            return self.connectedTo.keys()
    def getId(self):
            return self.id
    def getWeight(self,nbr):
            return self.connectedTo[nbr]
    def setColor(self,c):
            self.color=c
    def getColor(self):
            return self.color
    def setDistance(self,d):
            self.dist=d
    def getDistance(self):
            return self.dist
    def setPred(self,u):
            self.pred=u
    def getPred(self):
            return self.pred
    def getsTime(self):
            return self.sTime
    def getfTime(self):
            return self.fTime
    def setsTime(self,t):
            self.sTime=t
    def setfTime(self,t):
            self.fTime=t

class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
            self.vertList={}
            self.numVertices=0
            self.time=0
    def addVertex(self,id):
            self.numVertices=self.numVertices+1
            newVertex=Vertex(id)
            self.vertList[id]=newVertex
    def getVertex(self,id):
            if id in self.vertList:
                    return self.vertList[id]
            else:
                    return None
    def __contains__(self,id):
            return id in self.vertList
    def addEdge(self,u,v,weight=0):
            if u not in self.vertList:
                    self.addVertex(u)
            if v not in self.vertList:
                    self.addVertex(v)
            self.vertList[u].addNeighbor(self.vertList[v],weight)
    def getVertices(self):
            return self.vertList.keys()
    def __iter__(self):
            return iter(self.vertList.values())
    def bfs(self,start):
            self.vertList[start].setDistance(0)
            self.vertList[start].setColor("gray")
            q=Queue()
            q.enqueue(self.vertList[start])
            while(q.size()>0):
                    u=q.dequeue()
                    u.setColor("black")
                    for v in u.connectedTo:
                            if v.getColor()=="white":
                                    v.setColor("gray")
                                    v.setDistance(u.getDistance()+1)
                                    v.setPred(u)
                                    q.enqueue(v)

                    print"Id ",u.getId()," color ",u.getColor()," Distance ",u.getDistance()
```